# C Program that adds together square numbers - doesnt work

Tags: sum, ansi-c

So I want to create an array with all the square numbers up to 1000000. And then I add the numbers together.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int squareNumbers[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while (i <= 1000){
        squareNumbers[i] = i*i;
        i++;
    }

    while (i >= 0) {
        sum= sum + squareNumbers[i];
        i--;
     }

printf("Sum: %d", sum);
```

My problem is that I can execute the program however the printf in the end doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code references to an index that is out of the array's range.

On the first `while` loop, `i` increases up to `1001` and references `squareNumbers[1000]`, which is over the maximum index it can have (999).

To fix this,

1. remove `=` on the first loop.
2. reduce `i` by 1 after the first loop.

code:

```
int squareNumbers[1000];
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;

while (i < 1000){
    squareNumbers[i] = i*i;
    i++;
}

i--;
while (i >= 0) {
    sum= sum + squareNumbers[i];
    i--;
 }

printf("Sum: %d", sum);
```

However, this will sum from `0*0` to `999*999` following the range of `i`.

So you can change from

```
squareNumbers[i] = i*i;
```

to

```
squareNumbers[i] = (i+1)*(i+1);
```

So it has the sum from `1*1` to `1000*1000`.